# Cannot do my first git push on github

Tags: git, github

I have forked a project in github, with no problem, and cloned it to my local system.

I've made some changes, and it's now time to do `git push`.  The URL is of type `https`.

I'm working in Linux, and have the environment variable `https_proxy` and `http_proxy`, pointing to CNTLM, that requires no authentication.

```
http_proxy=http://localhost:5865
https_proxy=https://localhost:5865
```

Here is the result I get:

```
$ git push
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myuser/myproject.git/': Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
```

I suspect of the proxy.  If I remove the environment variables, it fails quicker.

I've managed to work successfully with `git`, proxies and the `ssh` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

It was a temporary problem in Github.

The word `proxy` has confused me, because I'm used to have problems with proxies.